# Automatically include helper modules in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just scaffolded an `User` and I want to automatically include the helpers defined in the `UsersHelper` module, as well as the ones defined in `ApplicationHelper`.

In other words, I'd like to load every helper in the `app/helpers` folder without having to manually `include FooHelper` every time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, go to your `ApplictionController` and add

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helpers :all
end
```

That said, I suggest you look at implementing presenters/decorators instead of using 'helpers'.  They are just POROs, and here's a blog post of mine on the topic: http://mwdesilva.com/posts/63-decorator-and-presenter-patterns-in-rails-3-2-x